# file save permissions on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I work a code saving an image file, it works very well, but when I change the directory I get gdi generic error.
How can I change the file permissions when using Visual Studio?

Working code:

```
y.Save(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\123.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Not working:

```
string path="C:\\Users\\tek\\Desktop\\twster\\ASP.NET\\images";
y.Save(System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(path) + "\\123.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

How can I change file save permissions when I use Visual Studio or make the work second code?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you mean here. Visual Studio has nothing to do with Writing/Reading Permissions of you code. The problem will come from the issue that your Web Application isn't allowed to write to the specific folder. Granting the application rights to this folder, is pretty useless once you deploy.

Comment: this code will work only if current logged in user is 'twster' because only that user has access to the desktop directory

Comment: this code will not compile you cant use a variable befor you initialize this. You use "path" in the first line and in the second one you declare and initialize them. That will not work!

Comment: @NitinSawant logged user is already same

Comment: @Darem sorry for the fault , first i initialize path then tried to save but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the path on your working code is not equivalent to the code on Not working code.

The equivalent absolute path of `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` is : 
`%userprofile%\appdata\local\temp`

First code will work because it gives you temporary path of currently logged in user. Second code doesn't work because you're requesting Desktop Access for specific user. If you need to save to absolute path, try saving to some other drive or location where everyone has access.